# How can I run tests on all combinations?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm using xUnit.net as my testing framework, but I suppose this question applies to other frameworks.  My method below takes two booleans.  How can I test all combinations without having to write out each combination?

```
    [Theory,
    InlineData(false, false),
    InlineData(true, false),
    InlineData(false, true),
    InlineData(true, true)]
    public void Foo(bool A, bool B )
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
    [Theory,
    SomeAttribute( for(int i=0; i<5; i++), for(int y=0; y<5; y++)),
    public void Foo(int A, int B )
```

that would run this test 5x5=25 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static IEnumerable<object[]> FooData
    {
        get
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++)
                {
                   yield return new object[] {a > 0, b > 0};
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    [Theory]
    [PropertyData("FooData")]
    public void Foo(bool A, bool B)
```

Comment: PropertyData is now obsolete in favor of MemberData

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more clever ways to accomplish this...

Just adding in case it isn't immediately apparent for someone how to easily expand the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684648/8055878) from @WhiskerBiscuit to account for additional boolean parameters.

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> FooData
{
    get 
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++)
                    {
                        yield return new object[] { a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0 };
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(FooData))]
public void Foo(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.Combinatorial. Then it's just a case of adding the `[CombinatorialData]` attribute to your test.